# Writing from Spark into Greenplum Database using greenplum-connector-apache-spark-scala_2.12-2.1.0 - java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, greenplum

Writing from Spark into Greenplum Database using greenplum-connector-apache-spark-scala_2.12-2.1.0 - java.lang.IllegalStateException

Greenplum version:
PostgreSQL 9.4.24 (Greenplum Database 6.8.1 build commit:xxxxxxx) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit compiled on Jun 16 2020 18:53:13

Connector :
greenplum-connector-apache-spark-scala_2.12-2.1.0.jar

Spark Version:
Welcome to spark version 3.1.2

Using Scala version 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_312)

ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkSession should only be created and accessed on the driver.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

val gscWriteOptionMap = Map(
      "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:5432/database",
      "user" -> "user",
      "password" -> "pass",
      "dbschema" -> "schema",
      "dbtable" -> "table"
)
dataFrame.write.format("greenplum")
      .options(gscWriteOptionMap)
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .save()

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

22/01/14 12:02:29 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkSession should only be created and accessed on the driver.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$assertOnDriver(SparkSession.scala:1126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:919)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GpfdistServiceManager$.getService(GpfdistServiceManager.scala:59)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.<init>(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:67)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRDD.compute(GreenplumRDD.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD.compute(SQLExecutionRDD.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
22/01/14 12:02:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12) (spark executor driver): java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkSession should only be created and accessed on the driver.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$assertOnDriver(SparkSession.scala:1126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:919)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GpfdistServiceManager$.getService(GpfdistServiceManager.scala:59)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.<init>(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:67)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRDD.compute(GreenplumRDD.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD.compute(SQLExecutionRDD.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

22/01/14 12:02:29 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
22/01/14 12:02:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 13) (spark executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
22/01/14 12:02:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 11) (spark executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12) (spark executor driver): java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkSession should only be created and accessed on the driver.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$assertOnDriver(SparkSession.scala:1126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:919)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GpfdistServiceManager$.getService(GpfdistServiceManager.scala:59)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.<init>(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:67)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRDD.compute(GreenplumRDD.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD.compute(SQLExecutionRDD.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2258)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2207)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2445)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2387)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2376)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2196)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2291)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$fold$1(RDD.scala:1183)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.fold(RDD.scala:1177)
  at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider.saveDataFrame(GreenplumRelationProvider.scala:158)
  at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider.createRelation(GreenplumRelationProvider.scala:115)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:301)
  ... 55 elided
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkSession should only be created and accessed on the driver.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$assertOnDriver(SparkSession.scala:1126)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:919)
  at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GpfdistServiceManager$.getService(GpfdistServiceManager.scala:59)
  at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.<init>(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:67)
  at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRDD.compute(GreenplumRDD.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD.compute(SQLExecutionRDD.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: `SparkSession should only be created and accessed on the driver` means you tried to use SparkSession in your udf or lambda function which is not possible.

Comment: @mazaneicha, thanks for your reply. How can I write my dataframe to greenplum database? pls help, URL which I have referred https://greenplum-spark.docs.pivotal.io/1-6/rw_example.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue by downgrading Spark to 2.1.3.